# Lombok Remove red underline on IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lombok

I'm attempting to use Lombok for the first time since I have many variables in a class and don't want to generate getters and setters for all of them.

I'm using IntelliJ 2016.2.1 with the Lombok plugin 0.13.14 and my source code is in Java 8. I've enabled annotation pre-processing or whatever it was called and added lombok.jar to my libraries. I compiled my project and it compiles fine, with @Getter and @Setter methods working.

However, my only issue is I don't actually see the getters/setters in my IntelliJ help popup (the thing that shows up when you're midway typing a method and it gives you a list of fields/method names that you can use), and also any getter method I use shows a red line under it (still compiles fine).

How do I remove this red underline from Lombok generated methods, and is it possible to show the methods in the IntelliJ popup.

Comment: Did you google "lombok intellij"?

Comment: @Arkadiy Yep, https://i.gyazo.com/a276a34875cbd5f2b2d6860da443396e.png

Comment: You did not mention lombok plugin. Did you try it?

Answer (score 5):

Figured out I had installed the lombok plugin manually which happens to be an older version, the latest version works (installing via. IntelliJ).